# juju charm tools installation

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, juju

I am new to juju charms and I was trying to install juju charm tools as per the [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ_blv9JhCs).

I have installed a vm image for ubuntu on a windows box. The ubuntu version details are:

Linux vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I was able to successfully to run the steps mentioned in the tutorial till "juju bootstrap". Only for juju bootstrap, I am getting the following error -

```
  Bootstrapping environment "local"
Starting new instance for initial state server
Building tools to upload (1.24.3.1-vivid-amd64)

Bootstrapping environment "local"
Starting new instance for initial state server
Building tools to upload (1.24.3.1-vivid-amd64)

Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Logging to /home/vagrant/.juju/local/cloud-init-output.log on remote host
Installing package: curl
Installing package: cpu-checker
Installing package: bridge-utils
Installing package: rsyslog-gnutls
Installing package: cloud-utils
Installing package: cloud-image-utils
Installing package: tmux
Bootstrapping Juju machine agent
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
cpu-checker is already the newest version.
cpu-checker set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
bridge-utils is already the newest version.
bridge-utils set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
rsyslog-gnutls is already the newest version.
rsyslog-gnutls set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cloud-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,568 B of archives.
After this operation, 31.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main cloud-utils all 0.27-0ubuntu15 [1,568 B]
Fetched 1,568 B in 5s (296 B/s)
Selecting previously unselected package cloud-utils.
(Reading database ... 66876 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cloud-utils_0.27-0ubuntu15_all.deb ...
Unpacking cloud-utils (0.27-0ubuntu15) ...
Setting up cloud-utils (0.27-0ubuntu15) ...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
cloud-image-utils is already the newest version.
cloud-image-utils set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
tmux is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
945f7daba6d7d7f7d441d6536d513a61b6ccaf92d858bbc86a0038c9b97bd01d  /home/vagrant/.juju/local/tools/1.24.3.1-vivid-amd64/tools.tar.gz
2015-07-29 21:37:51 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running jujud [1.24.3.1-vivid-amd64 gc]
2015-07-29 21:37:51 INFO juju.network network.go:194 setting prefer-ipv6 to false
2015-07-29 21:37:51 INFO juju.provider.local environprovider.go:38 opening environment "local"
2015-07-29 21:37:54 INFO juju.agent identity.go:22 writing system identity file
2015-07-29 21:37:54 INFO juju.mongo mongo.go:173 Ensuring mongo server is running; data directory /home/vagrant/.juju/local; port 37017
2015-07-29 21:37:54 INFO juju.mongo mongo.go:348 installing juju-mongodb
2015-07-29 21:37:54 INFO juju.utils.packaging.manager utils.go:57 Running: apt-get --option=Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold --option=Dpkg::options::=--force-unsafe-io --assume-yes --quiet install juju-mongodb
2015-07-29 21:42:55 INFO juju.worker.peergrouper initiate.go:77 finished MaybeInitiateMongoServer
```

***>     **2015-07-29 21:42:55 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:430 cannot initiate replica set: cannot dial mongo to initiate replicaset: no

> reachable servers
> ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: exit status 1*****

I have tried destroy-environment and run the bootstrap command again. It seems from the messages that juju-mongodb is installed but I don't see the service running. I could not get the service to run using -

sudo service mongodb start.

The output is:

> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64:~$ sudo service mongod start
> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

What am I doing wrong? How do I check if mongodb is installed correctly?